# Why is it Pet Sematary but not Pet Cemetery?

Tags: title, pet-sematary-1989

My question is about Stephen King's [Pet Sematary (1989)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098084/). Why is *cemetery* misspelled as *sematary* in the title? Is there a special reason which may be explained in the novel or in the movie?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Pet Sematary is based on the novel of the same name. The name is described by the elderly neighbor, Jud. He explains that it was created by the children of the neighborhood to bury their dead animals killed on the heavily travelled road. The children had misspelled the name when it was created.

Quoting the Stephen King novel:

*...It narrowed, and then, just ahead, Louis saw Ellie and Jud go under an arch made of weatherstained boards. Written on these in faded black paint, only just legible, were the words PET SEMATARY.*

Comment: In addition, the novel and the spelling are based on an actual place which was behind King's own home.

Answer (score 15):

I remember it as the sign placed by the children of that town. They [misspelled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_Sematary) it while putting it up.